# Python cut a string after Xth sentence

Tags: python, string

I have to cut a **unicode** string which is actually an article (contains sentences) I want to cut this article string after Xth sentence in python.

A good indicator of a sentence ending is that it ends with full stop (".") and the word after start with capital name. Such as

```
myarticle == "Hi, this is my first sentence. And this is my second. Yet this is my third."
```

How can this be achieved ?

Thanks

Comment: Watch out for sentences that talk about Dr. Livingston, Mr. Peabody, Prof. Plum, or Mrs. O'Leary.

Comment: Also watch out for sentences that end with ? or !

Comment: Or sentences that use an ellipsis...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider downloading the Natural Language Toolkit ([`NLTK`](http://www.nltk.org/)). Then you can create sentences that will not break for things like "U.S.A." or fail to split sentences that end in "?!".

```
>>> import nltk
>>> paragraph = u"Hi, this is my first sentence. And this is my second. Yet this is my third."
>>> sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(paragraph)
[u"Hi, this is my first sentence.", u"And this is my second.", u"Yet this is my third."]
```

Your code becomes much more readable. To access the second sentence, you use notation you're used to.

```
>>> sentences[1]
u"And this is my second."
```

Comment: seems great but I am not able to import tokenize_sents from nltk. What library do I need?

regards.

Comment: @Hellnar sorry about this, from memory I had the incorrect function. try again with `nltk.sent_tokenize()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more robust solution:

```
myarticle = """This is a sentence.
   And another one.
   And a 3rd one."""

N = 3  # 3 sentences

print ''.join(sentence+'.' for sentence in re.split('\.(?=\s*(?:[A-Z]|$))', myarticle, maxsplit=N)[:-1])
```

This solution has a few advantages over some of the other possibilities mentioned before:

1. It works even when there are exactly `N` sentences in your text.  Some other answers yield a double `.` at the end.  This is avoided here by taking into account the fact that the last sentence is not followed by an uppercase letter, but by an end-of-text (`$`).
2. This works even when there are fewer than `N` sentences in the text.
3. The number of splits is limited by the `maxsplit` argument to `re.split()`, which limits the number of splittings and is therefore quite efficient.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If there can be other punctuation marks than the usual '.', you should probably try this:

```
re.split('\W(?=[A-Z])',ss)
```

This returns the list of the sentences. Of course, it does not treat correctly the cases mentioned by Paul.

Comment: This does not work with something like "The WWF breaks this."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'.'.join(re.split('\.(?=\s*[A-Z])', myarticle)[:2]) + '.'
```

It cuts your string after the second sentence ([:2]).

However there are some problems (as always if you deal with natural language): Most notably it will only recognize a sentence that starts with 'A-Z'. That might be true for English but not for other languages.

Comment: +1 but just because I can't vote +2 :) . regular expressions are so powerful.

Comment: This fails with "1st sentence. 2nd sentence."…

Comment: @EOL : Is it just pb with the final '.' ? I don't think that it worths a -1. I think it is still a nice one line solution even if other longer solution might be better

Comment: re.split('\.(?=\s+[A-Z])', myarticle) will not break U.S.A. but will require a space after full stop.

Comment: @luc: Yes, there is a double '.' when there are N or fewer sentences in the input text.  This is perfectly avoidable with a relatively short one-liner (as in my answer, for instance).  Regular expressions *are* indeed powerful, so it's best to use their power. :)